# AFrame - How can I configure zoom and pan controls through mouse instead of WASD controls, or else if possible both together in one project

Tags: three.js, aframe, webvr, webxr

I built one project with Aframe, ThreeJS, and angular, here I'm trying to change my zoom/pan controls to mouse, but I'm having controls using WASD keys or arrow keys on the keyboard with the mouse, I need to change the controls to the mouse scroll wheel and buttons. If possible both controls in the same project

I expect to whole control using a mouse, If possible both ones.